# Android: TextView alignment with respect to RadioGroup

Tags: android, textview, radio-group

Hi i'm trying to implement the following design (RadioGroup is parallel to TextView of rignt side)

[image]

for this requirement i wrote the bellow xml code

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_group_create_group_privacy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl_group_create_group_icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rl_bg_board_group_create_group"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_group_create_group_privacy"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/group_create_new_group_privacy"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rg_group_create_group_privacy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_group_create_group_privacy"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_group_create_group_public"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="@string/group_create_new_group_public"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_group_create_group_closed"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="@string/group_create_new_group_closed"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_group_create_group_secret"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="@string/group_create_new_group_secret"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_group_create_group_privacy_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rg_group_create_group_privacy"
                android:background="@color/White" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_group_create_group_public_desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/group_create_new_group_public_desc"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_group_create_group_closed_desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_group_create_group_public_desc"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/group_create_new_group_closed_desc"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_group_create_group_secret_desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_group_create_group_closed_desc"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/group_create_new_group_secret_desc"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

But it changing the alignment according to the device like the following picture (Some times radio button at middle of textView and some times at starting of textView and some more times at end of textView). By implementing the design in `layout-large, layout-small, layout-xlarge` we can achieve this some how but i don't want to follow. So, how to implement first image design without following `layout-large, layout-small, layout-xlarge`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this may helpful to you

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_group_create_group_privacy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_group_create_group_icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_group_create_group_privacy"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Privacy"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_group_create_group_public"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_group_create_group_privacy"
                android:checked="false"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:text="Public"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_group_create_group_public_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rb_group_create_group_public"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="group_create_new_group_public_desc"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_group_create_group_closed"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="Closed"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_group_create_group_closed_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rb_group_create_group_closed"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="group_create_new_group_closed_desc"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_group_create_group_privacy_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_group_create_group_secret"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="Secret"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_group_create_group_secret_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rb_group_create_group_secret"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="group_create_new_group_secret_desc"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

In Activity

```
 final RadioButton rbPublic = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_group_create_group_public);
        final RadioButton rbCloses = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_group_create_group_closed);
        final RadioButton rbSecret = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_group_create_group_secret);

        rbPublic.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    rbCloses.setChecked(!isChecked);
                    rbSecret.setChecked(!isChecked);
                }
            }
        });
        rbCloses.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    rbPublic.setChecked(!isChecked);
                    rbSecret.setChecked(!isChecked);
                }
            }
        });
        rbSecret.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    rbCloses.setChecked(!isChecked);
                    rbPublic.setChecked(!isChecked);
                }
            }
        });
```